# Как сюда добавить условие f неравно null?

Tags: c#

Как сюда добавить условие добавить если `f != null` ?

```
var files = filesA.Select((f) => new FileInfo(f))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для фильтрации воспользуйтесь методом **Where**. Вот так:

```
var files = filesA.Where(f => f != null).Select(f => new FileInfo(f));
```